# Python list in csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a question about how to save a list as a CSV file in my way:

If I have a big list with many sub-lists:
    records = [['a','b','c','d'], ['1','2','3','4'], ......]

and i use this code to generate a csv file:

```
import csv
create = csv.writer(open(filename, "wb"))
create.writerow(records)
```

it displays all sub-list in one row and each one is in one cell: ['a','b','c','d'] ['1','2','3','4'].....

However i don't want the square brackets and quotation marks, but want every item in one cell, and only one sub-list per row: a,b,c,d        1,2,3,4

I'm new to python and really know few about the codes. hope u can help me :)

Comment: Have you tried to loop on your data and call writerow() for each of them ?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(records)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
create = csv.writer(open(filename, "wb"))
for element in record:
    create.writerow(element)
```

Should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `records` structure. Something like this:

```
for x in records:
    create.writerow(x)
```